# php post input validation

Tags: php, validation

how can I validate on test.php to echo all of the entered text for fname value to be echo as text and only text whether its html,js or php

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
Enter Your name : <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 0):

this is the key
`htmlspecialchars()`

Answer (score 0):

[`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) will achieve what you need.

An example:

```
if (isset($_POST['txtExample'])) {
    echo(htmlentities($_POST['txtExample']), ENT_QUOTES));
}
```

Good luck.